# Cannot create class with a field of type Pointer with Parse Schema API

Tags: api, rest, parse-platform, schema

I'm using Parse, and trying to create a class with the Schema API which has a field of type Pointer. Here's what I'm doing:

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: $PARSE_APP_ID" \
    -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: $PARSE_APP_MASTER_KEY" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d ' 
    {
        "className": "Article",
        "fields": {
            "heading": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "author": {
                "type": "Pointer",
                "classname": "Author"
            }
        }
    }' \
    https://api.parse.com/1/schemas/Article
```

This fails with the following error from the API:

```
{"code":135,"error":"type Pointer needs a class name"}
```

The Author class already exists. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out. Use `targetClass` as the property name, not `className`.

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: $PARSE_APP_ID" \
    -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: $PARSE_APP_MASTER_KEY" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d ' 
    {
        "className": "Article",
        "fields": {
            "heading": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "author": {
                "type": "Pointer",
                "targetClass": "Author"
            }
        }
    }' \
    https://api.parse.com/1/schemas/Article
```

Comment: This was a really difficult find, it's not even in the official documentation as far as I could see.  Thanks for this.

Comment: @Frankie Thanks saved my day